# Using Magick++ in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, imagemagick, magick++

I am creating a Qt widget with a backend representation I wrote separately.  The backend uses Magick++, and I can get it to compile from the command line:

> g++ -c ../SpriteCreator/WriteGIF.cpp sprite.cpp -I ../SpriteCreator/ `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs` -O2

but when I try to compile the project Qt Creator it tells me

> /home/tpope/obeyYourThirst/qtSpriteEditor/backend/sprite.cpp:15: error: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
>    #include < Magick++.h>

I added the path for Magick++.h to the INCLUDEPATH, but now it has an error similar to this:

> /home/tpope/obeyYourThirst/qtSpriteEditor/backend/sprite.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'

for every use of a Magick function. It seems to be not including the library. How do I do that in Qt Creator?

Comment: You need to put the `Magick++-config` stuff inside `$()` like this... `$(Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs)` to actually execute them,

Comment: They were in backquotes in my makefile, but the markdown apparently removed those. It works in my makefile. How do I get Qt Creator to execute them?

Comment: As a temporary fix, run the `Magick++-config... -- ... --ldflags --libs` command I gave above in your Terminal, and copy and paste the output into your Qt Creator Makefile and see if that fixes it for now.

Comment: I just did that, and it worked. Thanks! I still wish I could get Qt Creator to simply run $(Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags --ldflags --libs) though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the .pro files in Qt Creator is (as far as I can tell) used to generate a Makefile, we can use make's ability to run a program on the shell and save its output.

I have added:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $(shell Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags)`

and

`LIBS += $(shell Magick++-config --ldflags --libs)`

to my .pro file, and I was able to add:

`#include <Magick++.h>`

to my program without a compile error, then compile a simple example (Just put out an animated .gif with a couple of colored pixels)

This obviously makes things like cross-compiling a little tricky (I don't know how to reference foreign libraries), but that's a problem for another time.